# obtener valores de un JSON

Tags: jquery, json

tengo una función que recibe un json `[{"id":"16"},{"v_service":"N009-SR000027938"},{"rbantesi":"1"}.....` deseo recorrerlo con jquery para obtener los datos por separado : "v_service, rbantesi, ...." y "N009-SR000027938, 1, ...." y no puedo, he intentado de la siguiente forma

```
function leer_ao(datos){
datos.forEach(function(registro){
    alert(JSON.stringify(registro));
    for (dato in registro){
        alert(dato);    
    }
});
```

}

Acá esta la función que estoy tratando de utilizar pero no puedo mostrar los dos datos
gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer solo te falta agregar otro `forEach` al registro para obtener el `indice` y el `valor`, estos pasandolo como parametro a `function`.

Ejemplo:

```
function leer_ao(datos){
    datos.forEach(function(registro){
        //alert(JSON.stringify(registro));
        registro.forEach(function(valor, indice) {
            alert(indice+":"+valor);
        });   
    });
}
```

Comment: Creo que aqui lo escribiste mal: forEacha

Comment: @BetaM gracias por la observación.

Comment: @jcHernande2, Muchas gracias por tu ayuda...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar map y si quieres los keys puedes usar `Object.keys(obj)`

```js
let dataToMap = [{
  "id": "16"
}, {
  "v_service": "N009-SR000027938"
}, {
  "rbantesi": "1"
}];


var arrayMapped = dataToMap.map((e, f) => Object.keys(e));
console.log(arrayMapped);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @x-rw

Comment: @CristianFuentesCasanova funciono?